# Finding an Edge that will Decrease the Max Flow if Deleted

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, network-flow, ford-fulkerson

Assume we are given a flow network G=(V, E) where every edge has capacity 1.
I want to design an efficient algorithm to find an edge e such that removing it from G would result in a G' with a lesser max (s, t)-flow than G.

I thought of several properties that G has:

- Flow of any edge is binary; there is either flow or no flow
- Increasing flow of an edge is equivalent to reversing it on the residual graph
- Number of nonzero ingoing edges = number of nonzero outgoing edges for all intermediate nodes
- Altering any edge on a (s, t)-path removes all flow from that path

Besides running Ford-Fulkerson and choosing any edge belonging to a min (s, t)-cut, I can't think of anything else.

Using the fact that G only contains edges of capacity 1, is there a more efficient algorithm? Thanks.

Comment: Seems unlikely that you'd be able to do this without finding a max flow or a min cut.  Edmonds-Karp is pretty simple with unit weights, and the complexity drops a bit to O(|E|^2)